# SimplePie Fatal Error: Call to a member function get_base() on a non-object (Line 176)

Tags: php, mysql, cron, simplepie

I hope someone got some tips for me.

I'm having an issue with SimpePie updating my MySQL database. I'm using it to fetch an array of RSS feeds based on a small tweak of the code below.

The weird part is the the script works fine when I execute it myself in my browsers, but NOT when it's executed by a CRON task by GoDaddy.

My CRON task looks like this, nothing magical:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/gia_rss_cron.php"
```

The error message returned via GoDaddy is as follows:

> **Fatal error:**  Call to a member function get_base() on a non-object in /home/content/40/xxx/html/php2/library/SimplePie/Item.php on line 167

The code that does the job is based on this code, I've tried *SimplePie 1.3.1* as well as 1.4dev just in case. Same error thrown on both, but as mentioned only when it's ran via CRON, not when I manually run the file.

```
<?php
require_once('php/autoloader.php');
$feed = new SimplePie();
// Create a new instance of SimplePie
// Load the feeds
$urls = array(
  'http://abcfamily.go.com/service/feed?id=774372' => 'abc',
  'http://www.insideaolvideo.com/rss.xml' => 'aolvideo',
  'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml' => 'bbcwn',
  'http://www.bing.com' => 'bing',
  'http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news' => 'espn',
  'http://www.xfinitytv.com/' => 'xfinitytv',
);
$feed->set_feed_url(array_keys($urls));
$feed->enable_cache(false);
//$feed->set_cache_location('cache');
//$feed->set_cache_duration(1800); // Set the cache time
//$feed->set_item_limit(1);
$success = $feed->init(); // Initialize SimplePie
$feed->handle_content_type(); // Take care of the character encoding
?>
<?php require_once("inc/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("inc/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>
<?php
// Sort it
$feed_items = array();
// $feed_items is an array
$items = $feed->get_items();
//$items is everything that $items = $feed->get_items(); produces
$urls = array_unique($urls);
// $url = is an empty $
foreach ($urls as $url => $image) {
  $unset = array();
  $feed_items[$url] = array();
  foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    if ($item->get_feed()->feed_url == $url) {
      $feed_items[$url][] = $item;
      $unset[] = $i;
    }
  }
  foreach ($unset as $i) {
    unset($items[$i]);
  }
}
foreach ($feed_items as $feed_url => $items) {
  if (empty($items)) { ?>
  <div class="item element" data-symbol="<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>" name="<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>">
  <div class="minimise"><img src="images/boreds/<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>.png"/>
  <div class="minimise2">
    <a href="<?php echo $feed_url; ?>"><h2>Visit <?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?> now!</h2></a>
  </div></div>
  <div class="maximise">
    <a href="<?php echo $feed_url; ?>"><h2>Visit <?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?> now!</h2></a>
  </div></div>

  <?
    continue;
  }
  $first_item = $items[0];
  $feed = $first_item->get_feed();
  ?>

  <?php

$feedCount = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $feedCount++;
  ?>
<div class="item element" " data-symbol="<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>" name="<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>">
<div class="minimise"><strong id="amount"><?php echo ''.$feedCount; ?></strong>
  <img src="images/boreds/<?php echo $urls[$feed_url] ?>.png"/>
  <div class="minimise2"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
  <h2><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h2></a>
</div></div>
<div class="maximise"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
   <h2><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h2></a><br><p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
</div></div>
<?php
  }
}
?>
<?php require("inc/footer2.php"); ?>
```

**Update**: Adding the code from item.php part of the SimplePie libary in case that helps, that's the only line 167 I can see which calls that functions. Though again script works from my browser, just no via CRON (not sure where that brings us as far as narrowing down the issue).

Also tried with error reporting on the PHP, there are no other errors or warnings thrown by the script from a browser.

```
     /**
     * Get the base URL value from the parent feed
     * Uses `<xml:base>`
     * @param array $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_base($element = array())
    {
        return $this->feed->get_base($element);
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't call `get_base()`

Comment: The get_base() error comes form the SimplePie core package that I've not modified.

Comment: @Organizer  If you commented out get_base() in core to test, what happens?

Comment: Don't know anything about simplepie, but in your includes you are using relative paths. Try changing these includes and use `dirname(__FILE__)` in the path definitions.

Comment: Updating with dirname(__FILE__) did not make any change unfortunately

Comment: Commenting out the get base just moved the error to an Fatal error:  Call to a member function sanitize() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

It is not finding the feed information. That is the reason it end up with this error.

Where ever in your code if you find like this format,

```
$item->get_...
```

change it to like this format,

```
$item->get_feed()->get_....
```

For example, You could see in your code these lines,

```
$item->get_title()
$item->get_permalink()
$item->get_description()
```

And please change this line to,

```
$item->get_feed()->get_title()
$item->get_feed()->get_permalink()
$item->get_feed()->get_description()
```

And do the same for all if you find the format,

```
$item->get_...
```

Comment: Hmm, don't I cover that in the two foreach() loops, assigning the get_feed() so that the call to just $item->get_ is correct or equal to that. Will give it a go clearly and report back later today. Thanks.